# Fingerprint with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, fingerprint

I want to implement a fingerprint to authorize users.

Anyone know how to start?

This application needs to be in NodeJS.

Atm, I found this 2 sources:

https://github.com/the-AjK/GT-511C3

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gt511c3

Someone want to help?

Thank You!

Comment: Update: I also found this repo, works with DigitalPersona Fingerprints. https://github.com/danielsrod/digitalpersona-core

Comment: First off, people need to know if you're writing a web app (with nodejs as the server) and you want to auth a client in he browser or are you writing some sort of native client app using nodejs (like using Electron)?